# Rails How to create multiple object with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want create multiple Indhold in Indhold model. But when I submit I only get 1 Indhold parameter and it create only 1 indhold, even if i have checked several checkboxes .
I want it to create new Indhold width those Check Checkboxes.
My indhold form:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'create'}, {:multipart => true} ) %>

   <% for indhold in Indhold.find(:all) %>
   <%= check_box_tag( "indholds[navn]", indhold.navn ) %>
    <%= indhold.navn %><br /> 
     <% end %>

 </div> 
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag( "Submit" ) %> 
  </div>
```

My indhold controller:

```
  def new
    @indhold = Indhold.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @indhold }
    end
  end

  def create
    @indhold = Indhold.new(params[:indhold])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @indhold.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@indhold, :notice => 'Indhold was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @indhold, :status => :created, :location => @indhold }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @indhold.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Best regards, 
Rails beginner

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create an Indhold containing children navn values from existing Indholds, but Indhold.navn doesn't seem to be a has_many - is that correct? Can you add the code for the Indhold model?

Comment: I am not trying to create an Indhold containing children navn. I am trying to create Many Indholds width checkboxes from indhold model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change indholds[navn] to indholds[navn][] in the checkbox tag. That will send multiple values to params. But Indhold.new is going to create only one new record. You would have to do something like this to create multiple records:

```
@indholds = []
@errors = []
params[:indhold][:navn].each do |navn|
  indhold = Indold.new(:navn => navn)
  if indhold.valid?
    @indholds << indhold.save
  else
    @errors += indhold.errors
  end
end
```

It's not really a standard use of new; I would change the action to multiple_new or similar. You'll also have to use @errors instead of @indhold.errors in the form.

Comment: I get a no method error. Can you please show me have the form and the controller should look like?